# Finding a way to use a better name for model in Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate. To build a query I use a block

```
try(Session session = getSession()) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Vendor where name = :name");
    query.setParameter("name", name);
    List<Vendor> vendors = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return vendors.get(0);
}
```

But `Vendor` is the model name, and I'd like to use `vendors`, the table name, so the query "reads correctly".

In my `hibernate.cfg.xml` I have the following line:

`<mapping class="com.mysite.vendor" />`

Is there a way to use the `vendors` name in Hibernate 5.3? Or am I stuck with this clumsy name in my queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the physical table name then use should `createNativeQuery`

```
Query query = session.createNativeQuery("from vendors where name = :name");
```

Recommended way is to use hiberate JPA except very complex query.

If you really want use native query, store the native query somewhere and used `namedQuery`